# Convert Unicode byte array to CString in vc++

Tags: visual-c++, unicode, mfc

I have a byte array of size 2, which contain a single UTF-16LE encoded Unicode character from the Basic Multilingual Plane.

```
BYTE b[2];
memset(b,0,2);
b[0] = 0x31;
b[1] = 0x00;   //In future this byte contain info when unicode use , but now 0x00.
```

Now I want to store it in `CString` or `TCHAR` .

**EDIT**

I did use

```
TCHAR tch = (TCHAR)b;  //tch = 'X'
```

How is this possible?

Comment: Protip: `BYTE b[2] = {};` works just as well, but is less noisy, easier to type, and much, much safer than `memset`.

Comment: By Unicode do you mean UTF-8? Or do you mean UTF-16 broken down into bytes?

Comment: @duDE I have trid this..but gives error the "'initializing' : cannot convert from 'BYTE [2]' to 'TCHAR *'"

Comment: Try `CString szString((TCHAR*)b);`

Comment: @RogerRowland `CString szString((TCHAR*)b);` only works as long as a) `TCHAR` is `char` (that is, in non-Unicode build), and b) `b[1] == 0`. As long as either of these conditions is false, you are trying to construct a string from a pointer to buffer that is not NUL-terminated.

Comment: `(TCHAR)b` doesn't do what you seem to think it does. `b` is a pointer (to the first element of the array). `(TCHAR)b` effectively extracts the low-order byte of the address being pointed to. Your array just happens to be located at an address of the form xxxxxx58, so that the low-order byte is 0x58 aka `'X'`.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik yess, good point about the null terminator - I missed that.

Comment: I couldn't get the casting methods suggested above to work (VS 2015 in 2016. Here is a technique I learned from the late Scott McPhillips who really knew MFC: get the CString buffer using GetBufferSetLength, set the buffer to nulls, copy your 2 b bytes over using memcpy_s, and then release the buffer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You seem to be saying that your `BYTE[2]` array contains a single Unicode codepoint (from basic plane) represented in UTF-16 (or UCS-2 - they are equivalent for basic plane). In this case, you can construct a one-character `CString` from it this way:

```
CStringW s((wchar_t*)b, 1);
```

or

```
CStringW s((wchar_t&)b);
```

It's not clear why you are using `BYTE[2]` and not `wchar_t` or `WCHAR` to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

simply:

```
BYTE recv_buffer[1024];
CString str_recv(recv_buffer);
```

Answer (score -1):

I couldn't get the casting methods suggested above to work (VS 2015 in 2016). Here is a technique I learned from the late Scott McPhillips who really knew MFC:

```
CString str;
LPWSTR strBuf = str.GetBufferSetLength( 4 ); // your b two bytes plus unicode trailing null
::memset( strBuf, 0, 4 ); // make sure the trailing bytes are null
::memcpy_s( strBuf, 2, b, 2 ); // copy over your byte bytes
str.ReleaseBuffer();
```